# Is $f$ a differentiable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hello everyone I have this problem, Can somebody help me with this?

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ is defined by:

$$f(x,y) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} \ln\left(\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}\right) & \mbox{if } xy\geq{0}
\\ 0 & \mbox{if }xy<0\end{matrix}\right. $$

Is $f$ a differentiable function?

Thanks for your help :D , have a nice day

Comment: What is the value of the function at the point $(0,0)$? How about $(1,0)$? And $(0,1)$?

Comment: The function behaves well (according to your definition) except on the axes. On these points, the function is clearly differentiable. However, at the axes, your function definition doesn't make sense, and so we can't talk about it being differentiable.

Comment: @CalvinLin       :o Thanks for your time and your answer, it help me a lot :D

Comment: @CalvinLin      For example if $x=0,\ y\neq 0$ we have ln(0) (doesn´t exist), if  $x\neq 0,\ y=0$ we have ln(x/0) (doesn´t exist), at the point (0,0) the same case doesn´t exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function behaves well (according to your definition) except on the axes. On these points, the function is clearly differentiable. However, at the axes, your function definition doesn't make sense (the values do not exist), and so we can't talk about it being differentiable.

Comment: $f$ isn´t a continuous function then $f$ can´t be  differentiable.

Thanks you very much

Comment: You're missing the point. It is not defined at those points at all. Consider the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. It is not defined at 0, so we can't say anything about the function at 0.

Comment: For example if $x=0,\ y\neq 0$ we have ln(0) (doesn´t exist), if  $x\neq 0,\ y=0$ we have ln(x/0) (doesn´t exist), at the point (0,0) the same case doesn´t exist

Answer (score 2):

Besides to @Calvin sufficient and strong deduction,the function as you defined it, is not continuous at least at the origin $(0,0)$. Take the path $y=mx$ for various $m$. This can be extended to other problematic points.

[image]

Comment: I'm  not sure what you mean by 'extended'. What other problematic points are there, where $xy \neq 0$?

Comment: @CalvinLin: I mean the points you have noted the OP.

Comment: $+1$ dear friend!

Comment: @amWhy: What happened to your answer in that question? Deleted? :-(

Comment: Yes, I deleted it. Someone downvoted it, after the question was edited. Perhaps I'll edit/update it and re-post it. Oh well. :-)

Comment: @amWhy: Plz undo that for later. ;-)